# DirectShow - How to rotate web cam preview video?

Tags: directshow

I am using DirectShow ICaptureGraphBuilder2, IVideoWIndow  & IGraphBuilder to preview web cam video into specified window.
I am successful to preview web cam view. Now, I want to rotate this web cam preview by 90 degree. Explored web and people suggest to use transform filter but I didn't exactly find how to do it. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN describes it in [Writing Transform Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and you will find some related discussions:

- [I want to Rotate a video with some angle](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/55815b73-f519-46e1-a2bc-ae3e838c945c/)
- [Need help on video in portrait mode](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/322152c9-34b5-4fa6-9497-24d787e20531)

The supposed transform filter needs to rearrange pixels in the data buffer, and also indicate the rotation on the media type.

Comment: Thanks Roman. Can you point to any code ? will be more helpful.

Comment: Why not? There is [Rotate Filter](http://videoprocessing.sourceforge.net/#rotate) on `Video Processing Project` at SourceForge.